# Почему нет подсказки в JSX тегов?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, почему в VS Code пишу в jsx файле термины из JS он мне подсказывает автодополнение, но если пишу теги HTML, то приходится его писать самому полностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code)

> Visual studio code по определяет .jsx расширение и добавляет emmet
> умолчанию.
>
> Но если вы предпочитаете использовать расширение .js для ваших React
> файлов вы можете ассоциировать JavaScript React с .js файлами в нижнем
> правом углу VS Code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]